# Have Jcrop in Django Admin for thumbnails?

Tags: jquery, django, jcrop

I'm new in the Django world, and I need some advice on how to add Jcrop in the Django admin.

Basically what I want:
1) In my model I have two image fields: origianl_image and a thumbnail_image
2) In the admin, a user upload an image
3) Then, we show him the jcrop pluging to crop the image as a thumbnail (width = height = 150px)

I already do 1) and 2), but have no idea how to do 3)
Any advice on how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try out [django-cropper](https://github.com/simonw/django_cropper/tree/master/cropper) or [django-image-cropping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping) - This plugin integrates the Jcrop plugin with the Django admin

Comment: Thanks! I already saw this, but I'm not comfortable using a project with no updates in the last three years.

Comment: Well, here you go - a more updated one - django-image-cropping